# How can I tell if my silver shark is pregnant?

Tags: fish, aquarium, breeding

I have two silver sharks in my aquarium. Today, I noticed that one seems to have a couple of bumps on its underbelly (see picture) also is hiding at the back of the tank, but usually swims around in the open area.

How can I confirm if this is pregnancy/carrying eggs (sorry I'm not sure of the biology on this), or something wrong with the fish? Also, if pregnant, what steps should I take next?

Shark1 not pregnant:[image: The "normal one"]

Shark2 possibly pregnant:[image: The "pregnant"? one]

Shark2 possibly pregnant:[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer was a no. There was something wrong with it. After doing more research it seems there could have been something stuck. Ultimately it died a couple of days later. Maybe someone else could give a more accurate answer as to what it could be, but pregnancy was defiantly incorrect

Comment: Sorry to hear : (